# JQuery - Why does this simple code not work in Explorer

Tags: jquery

Why does this simple thing not work in Internet Explorer 9? (works in FireFox)

```
var total = 0;
$("input[id=anzahl_feld]").each(function() {
    var anzahl = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(!isNaN(anzahl))
    {
        total += Anzahl;
    }
});
alert(total);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want quotes around the id field

```
$("input[id='anzahl_feld']")
```

But since ids are unique (or at least they should be), why not simply do

```
var $input = $("#anzahl_feld")
var anzahl = parseInt($input.val());
if(!isNaN(anzahl)) { 
     total += anzahl; 
}
```

If you actually *do* have multiple inputs with the id of `anzahl_feld` then *that's* probably why IE is choking.  **You cannot have multiple elements with the same id**

Comment: Wouldn't `$("#anzahl_feld")` be even faster?

Comment: Nope, does also not work. I've tried it with the name attribute and a individual one.. but nothing works :/  But thanks.

Comment: @qwertymk - yeah - I meant to type that originally - not sure what my brain was thinking as I was writing it out...

Comment: @Crayl - do you have multiple elements with this same id?

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes, but I have also tried the attribute name and an individual one. Or do you mean multiple IDs disturbe Explorer completly?

Comment: @Crayl - multiple IDs are **invalid**.  Other browsers may deal with it better than others, but this is fundamentally wrong.  You'll need to re-work your html so all elements have unique ids

Comment: @AdamRackis Damn it, you're right. IE seems to have problems with multiple ID's. I have tried it in a separate script and it f***ing works. I hate my life.

Comment: @Crayl - life's not so bad.  Depending on your situation, you might mark multiple elements with identical **css classes** and then select on that